# How to I move desktops between monitors and reorder them in Windows 10?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I use the Spaces feature in OS X quite heavily so when I heard Windows 10 would support a similar feature I was excited to try.

Upon attempting to build my virtual desktop workflow similar to that of what I had on OS X I noticed I cannot drag desktops around to reorder them, and I also cannot drag desktops between monitors.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't run windows 10, but I can't find *anything* about reordering virtual desktops, only moving windows between virtual desktops. I don't even see a KB on 'task view'

Answer (score 2):

> I also cannot drag desktops between monitors

Seems a single virtual desktop spans all your monitors, as opposed to being associated with a single monitor.

This means a window has association with the pair (Desktop, Monitor) as opposed to just desktop.

As for reordering desktops, I can find no information

Comment: I don't know why they didn't just copy Mission Control from OS X.

Comment: For one of the most obvious "enhancements" to Windows and especially Desktop, which is front and center to every new Windows user experience, Task View is remarkably poorly done.

Comment: haha good luck ever getting such an advanced feature... all I want is the ability to rearrange virtual desktops.. and I have my doubts that that will ever happen